# Gradle: how to declare a dependency to a specific configuration of a project programatically in java

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies

Following the setup described in [Simple sharing of artifacts between projects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/cross_project_publications.html#sec:simple-sharing-artifacts-between-projects), we are in the special case where we have a multi module gradle build that produce different types of jars and we would like to declare a dependency to those jar in a configuration.

```
dependencies {
    instrumentedClasspath(project(path: ":producer", configuration: 'instrumentedJars'))
}
```

from the docs works great.

In the project [dependency-tests](https://github.com/jmini/gradle-sandbox/tree/master/dependency-tests) I have a project that reproduce the setup (with different names, but the idea is the same).

---

But I am doing this in a Gradle-plugin and I would like to have the same declaration in java.

```java
DependencyHandler dependencyHandler = project.getDependencies();

// this adds a dependency to the main jar of the 'producer' project:
dependencyHandler.add("instrumentedClasspath", project.getRootProject().findProject(":producer"));

// this is not working:
dependencyHandler.add("instrumentedClasspath", project.getRootProject().findProject(":producer").getConfigurations().getByName("instrumentedJars"));
```

Failing with:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':printConf'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':instrumentedJars'.
   > Cannot convert the provided notation to an object of type Dependency: configuration ':producer:instrumentedJars' artifacts.
     The following types/formats are supported:
       - Instances of Dependency.
       - String or CharSequence values, for example 'org.gradle:gradle-core:1.0'.
       - Maps, for example [group: 'org.gradle', name: 'gradle-core', version: '1.0'].
       - FileCollections, for example files('some.jar', 'someOther.jar').
       - Projects, for example project(':some:project:path').
       - ClassPathNotation, for example gradleApi().
     
     Comprehensive documentation on dependency notations is available in DSL reference for DependencyHandler type.

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
project(...)
```

inside the `dependencies` block comes from the `DependencyHandler`, and

```
path: ":producer", configuration: 'instrumentedJars'
```

is actually a map {"path"=":producer", "configuration"="instrumentedJars"}.

So something like that should work in Java:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("path", ":producer"); 
map.put("configuration", "instrumentedJars");
dependencyHandler.add("instrumentedClasspath", dependencyHandler.project(map));
```

Note: When using Kotlin build script you can easily see types and declarations of functions and might be easier for discovering API. So in Kotlin `project(...)` in the `dependencies` block is an extension method defined as:

```
fun DependencyHandler.project(
    path: String,
    configuration: String? = null
): ProjectDependency =
    uncheckedCast(
        project(
            if (configuration != null) mapOf("path" to path, "configuration" to configuration)
            else mapOf("path" to path)
        )
    )
```